# SoapUI Setting a cookie session

Tags: xml, wsdl, soapui

I am using SoapUI to test my Soap requests and responses. The problem is that I was given 2 WSDL urls, so I had to create two separate projects, and the second project relies on cookies from the first project. So how can I set a persistent cookie session in SoapUI?

Comment: You can assign more than just one WSDL to one soapUI-project (right-click on project and select "Add WSDL" from context-menu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include both the WSDL in single project only....You need to do right click on your project and add WSDL and add the second WSDL ..it will generate new interface for you.You can do your work with the both wsdl in single project only.